# Modernizr: how to detect FullScreen API

Tags: javascript, modernizr

I want to detect the [FullScreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode) with [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), but I really can't understand how.

Here's what I tried:

```
console.log(Modernizr);               // Object {flexbox: true, canvas: true, …}
console.log(Modernizr.fullscreen);    // undefined 
console.log(Modernizr.fullscreenapi); // undefined
console.log(Modernizr.fullScreen);    // undefined
```

I've tried the [development version](http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js) and a custom build; and yes, I've checked `fullscreen-api` in the custom build.

Same problem with other non-core detects like `contenteditable`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/uRDQF/ - the minified Modernizr code is from their Download page, where the only things checked are "fullscreen-api" and "Modernizr._domPrefixes" (under Extensibility)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I attempted to uncheck everything but `fullscreen-api`; by the way, when unchecking `_domPrefixes` it was automatically unchecking `fullscreen-api` too. Redownloading the custom build with `fullscreen-api` and `_domPrefixes` both checked fixed my issue.

The right property to detect is of course `Modernizr.fullscreen`. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the class names feature? Do you see `fullscreen` or `no-fullscreen` on your `<html>` tag? If you do but you still can't access `Modernizr.fullscreen` you *could* just monkey patch it, but that's probably not ideal.

```
Modernizr.fullscreen = Modernizr.fullscreen || $('html').hasClass('fullscreen');
```

Otherwise, I would follow Ian's example and just dump your whole Modernizr file into a fiddle for others to look at.